# Ubuntu 14.04 apt-get dist-upgrade error on bcmwl-kernel-source

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade, kernel-module, apt-get

A dist-update I just did hung (froze) after printing line:

```
DKMS: install completed.
```

I had to close the terminal to kill process, and to carry on did

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
kill -15 THE-PID
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But dist-update and command below (with output) still hangs, freezes on statement:

```
DKMS: install completed.

$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing old bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  bcmwl
Version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom
Kernel:  3.13.0-24-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

wl.ko:
 - Uninstallation
 - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
 - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
 - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.30.223.248+bdcom completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-24-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-24-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
 - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....
DKMS: install completed.
```

I dont think reboot is right answer here. Might not boot at all!
Gad Zooks! Any tips & tricks?

Probably should have commands below before update/upgrade but only hind sight is 20/20

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my Broadcomm Wireless drivers do not play well with latest Ubuntu 14.04 updates.

I just removed debian packages bcmwl-kernel-source and dkms.

The packages might very well run fine, but apt-get upgrade hangs, and I don't want to to deal with contantly freezing updates.

Now I can run 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' and smooth sailing.